# Истинная медиана

Tags: c++

Пусть задана последовательность из N целых неотрицательных чисел. Назовем истинной медианой такой последовательности в случае нечетного N элемент, который будет равноудален от концов последовательности, если ее отсортировать по возрастанию или убыванию, а в случае четного N - среднее арифметическое двух таких соседних элементов. Напишите программу, которая по заданной входной последовательности вычисляет ее истинную медиану.

Ввод
В первой строке входа содержится число N — длина последовательности. Во второй и последующих строках расположены сами элементы последовательности, по одному в каждой строке. Длина последовательности — целое число от единицы до 250 000. Каждый элемент последовательности — целое число от 0 до (2^31−1) включительно.

Вывод
Программа должна выдать значение медианы с точностью до одного десятичного знака.

Ввод 4 3 6 4 5
Вывод 4.5

Мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    int n, i, elems_to_pop;
    double med;
    std::vector<int> v;

    n = i = 0;
    while(std::cin >> i){
        v.push_back(i);
        n++;
    }
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

    if(n & 0x1){    //n - нечетное
        elems_to_pop = (n - 1) / 2; //Сколько элементов снять с кучи, чтобы добраться до медианы
        while(elems_to_pop){
            std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            v.pop_back();
            med = v.front();
            elems_to_pop--;
        }
        std::cout << med;   //Медиана в случае нечетного n
    }else{  //n - четное
        elems_to_pop = (n / 2) - 1; //Сколько элементов снять с кучи перед расчетом медианы
        while(elems_to_pop){
            std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
            v.pop_back();
            med = v.front();
            elems_to_pop--;
        }
        std::cout << ((med + v.front()) / 2.0); //Медиана в случае четного n
    }
}
```

Код: https://ideone.com/QVkAbz

Я прав, что в условии или в примере входных данных ошибка, которую разносят по интернету (например, здесь http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?num=1306&locale=ru)?

Comment: Я не вижу ошибки во входных данных. 4 числа 3, 6, 4, 5 имеют медиану 4.5, так как ( 4 + 5 ) / 2 == 4.5

Comment: По условию здесь медиана - это элемент, равноудаленный от концов отсортированной последовательности. Он не может быть дробным.  по ссылке есть подтверждение этого: нетрудно сообразить, что этот элемент имеет номер (N+1)/2 в отсортированной последовательности, если номера считать с единицы

Comment: Это если у вас нечетное число элементов. А в примере данных, который вы показали, имеется четное число элементов. Поэтому берется среднее арифметическое двух элементов.

Comment: Нет, смотрите данные ОП посте. Ввод 4 3 6 4 5 Вывод 4.5

Comment: Первое число - это число элементов в последовательности.:)

Comment: О боже, я это пропустил что ли?

Comment: Странно, я что-то упустил. На каких-то входных данных программа работает неправильно. Даже непонятно, что можно было не учесть. Зато не проходи уже только 4-й тест. https://ideone.com/tNub1Z

Answer (score 1):

Входные данные соответствуют их описанию. Первое число представляет собой количество чисел в последовательности, а затем идут сами числа.

То есть для входных данных `4 3 6 4 5` 4 означает количество следующих за ней чисел последовательности, для которых нужно вычислить медиану. Нагляднее будет, если записать данные числа вертикально по строкам

```
4
3
6
4
5
```

Где первая строка содержит число, определяющее количество чисел в последовательности.

Если делать задачу прямолинейно, не заботясь об ее эффективности, то решение может выглядеть следующим образом (я вводил данные через консоль, а не файл):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n )
    {
        std::vector<int> v( n );

        std::partial_sort_copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ),
                                std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                                v.begin(), v.end() );

        std::cout << "median is equal to " << std::setprecision( 2 )
                  << ( n % 2 ? double( v[n / 2] ) : ( v[n / 2 - 1] + v[n / 2] ) / 2.0 )
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Результат, как и предполагается, равен

```
median is equal to 4.5
```

Чтобы программа работала с файлом, достаточно просто заменить `std::cin` на файловый поток.

А чтобы ускорить работу программы, то можно вместо вектора объявить статический массив целых чисел.

Например,

```
//...
const size_t N = 250'000;
int a[N];

int main()
{
    //...
```

В этом случае вызов алгоритма будет выглядеть как

```
    std::partial_sort_copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                            a, a + n );
```

А имя файла можно задавать через аргументы командной строки. То есть объявить `main` как

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет вы не правы, ошибки отсутвуют в условиях и примерных выходных данных.